# how to cast return of generic method in java?

Tags: java

```
public num sum (num x , num y )
{
     String out = (stringSum(String.valueOf(x),String.valueOf(y)));
     return ??

}
```

what should i write for return to cast out String to num (Like Integer , Float and ... )

Comment: You can't cast a string to any of those types. Casting doesn't perform those kinds of conversions in Java.

Comment: what's `num`???

Comment: Do you mean Wrapper classes Like (Integer, Double, etc...)?
then you can use methods like Double.parseDouble(out); to Wrap your string inside it and return as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a use case for generics: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html .

Make sure you understand well how it works, it behaves a bi differently than it may appear. I recommend reading this article several times :) - https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/generics-tutorial-159168.pdf .

Comment: This does not sounds like a use case for generics at all. The required types are known at compile time and are not changing between invocations. This is more about type *conversion* like transforming numbers to strings and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

To convert a String to a number you can use `Integer.parseInt(out)` or `Float.parseFloat(out)` (or similar functions for the other types of numbers).
You cannot convert to a generic 'num' directly. You have to know which type you want to get.

You can use `Number` as return type though, because both ints and floats (and doubles, bytes, short and longs) are subtypes of Number.